# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a new flight and display the values of its attributes in the console and return to the home page immediately after submitting. However, when I run the server, this error shows up(I am using react-router-dom v6):

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
onSubmit

Here's the code of CreateFlight component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";


export class CreateFlight extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onChangeFrom = this.onChangeFrom.bind(this);
        this.onChangeTo = this.onChangeTo.bind(this);
        this.onChangeCabin = this.onChangeCabin.bind(this);
        this.onChangeSeatNumber = this.onChangeSeatNumber.bind(this);
        this.onChangeFlightDate = this.onChangeFlightDate.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDepartureTime = this.onChangeDepartureTime.bind(this);
        this.onChangeArrivalTime = this.onChangeArrivalTime.bind(this);
        this.onChangeTerminal = this.onChangeTerminal.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            from: '',
            to: '',
            cabin: '',
            seatNumber: 0,
            flightDate: new Date(),
            departureTime: '',
            arrivalTime: '',
            terminal: 0,

        }
    }


    onChangeFrom(e) {
        this.setState({
            from: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeTo(e) {
        this.setState({
            to: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeCabin(e) {
        this.setState({
            cabin: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeSeatNumber(e) {
        this.setState({
            seatNumber: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeFlightDate(date) {
        this.setState({
            flightDate: date
        });
    }

    onChangeDepartureTime(e) {
        this.setState({
            departureTime: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeArrivalTime(e) {
        this.setState({
            arrivalTime: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeTerminal(e) {
        this.setState({
            terminal: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const flight = {
            from: this.state.from,
            to: this.state.to,
            cabin: this.state.cabin,
            seatNumber: this.state.seatNumber,
            flightDate: this.state.flightDate,
            departureTime: this.state.departureTime,
            arrivalTime: this.state.arrivalTime,
            terminal: this.state.terminal

        }

        console.log(flight)

        window.location = '/home';
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <div><br/>
                    <h3>Create New Flight </h3>
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>From: </label>
                            <input type="text"
                                required
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter departure city"
                                value={this.state.from}
                                onChange={this.onChangeFrom}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>To: </label>
                            <input type="text"
                                required
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter destination city"
                                value={this.state.to}
                                onChange={this.onChangeTo}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Cabin: </label>
                            <input type="text"
                                required
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Choose cabin class"
                                value={this.state.cabin}
                                onChange={this.onChangeCabin}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Seat Number: </label>
                            <input type="text"
                                required
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Choose seat number"
                                value={this.state.seatNumber}
                                onChange={this.onChangeSeatNumber}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Flight Date: </label>
                            <div>
                                <DatePicker
                                    selected={this.state.flightDate}
                                    onChange={this.onChangeFlightDate}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Departure Time: </label>
                            <input type="text"
                                required
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter departure time"
                                value={this.state.departureTime}
                                onChange={this.onChangeDepartureTime}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Arrival Time: </label>
                            <input type="text"
                                required
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter arrival time"
                                value={this.state.arrivalTime}
                                onChange={this.onChangeArrivalTime}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Terminal: </label>
                            <input type="text"
                                required
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Choose terminal number"
                                value={this.state.terminal}
                                onChange={this.onChangeTerminal}
                            />
                        </div><br/>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Create Flight" className="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

And here's the code of App component which renders CreateFlight component:

```
import './App.css';
import {Home} from './components/Home';
import {AvailableFlights} from './components/AvailableFlights';
import {FlightsSchedule} from './components/FlightsSchedule';
import {CreateFlight} from './components/CreateFlight';
import {Login} from './components/Login';
import {FindFlight} from './components/FindFlight';
import {Footer} from './components/Footer';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import { NavDropdown, Container, Navbar, Nav, Form, Button, FormControl} from "react-bootstrap";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';





function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar bg="dark" expand="lg" variant="dark" sticky="top" >
    <Container fluid>
      <Navbar.Brand id="nav_title" href="/home">Airline Reservation</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarScroll" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarScroll">
        <Nav
          className="me-auto my-2 my-lg-0"
          style={{ maxHeight: '100px' }}
          navbarScroll
        >
          <Nav.Link href="/home">Home</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/login">Login</Nav.Link>
          <NavDropdown title="Flights" id="navbarScrollingDropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/availableFlights">Available Flights</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/flightsSchedule">Flights Schedule</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/createFlight">Create Flight</NavDropdown.Item>
            {/* <NavDropdown.Divider /> */}
            {/* <NavDropdown.Item href="#action5">
              Something else here
            </NavDropdown.Item> */}
          </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
        <Form className="d-flex">
          <FormControl
            type="search"
            placeholder="Search"
            className="me-2"
            aria-label="Search"
          />
          <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
        </Form>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Container>
  </Navbar>
       <Routes>
         <Route path='/home' element={<Home />}/>
         <Route path='/login' element={<Login />}/>
         <Route path='/availableFlights' element={<AvailableFlights />}/>
         <Route path="/flightsSchedule" element={<FlightsSchedule />}/>
         <Route path='/createFlight' element={<CreateFlight />}/>
         <Route path='/findFlight' element={<FindFlight />}/>   
       </Routes>
       <Footer />
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind `this` for `onSubmit` method in the constructor.

```js
this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
```

**Recommendation:** You can use functional components with hooks for improving your speed and maintenance of codes in feature.

Comment: Thanks! @SaeedHemmati. Yes, I actually wanted to use Hooks instead, but I don't know how its syntax is written in the lastest update(dom v6), do you have any idea how it's done?

Comment: Your welcome. refactor class components to function components depends on app's scale and need many tests after refactoring. so you can use hooks in feature for new projects not this existing one.